# Unity 2D c# - How to save last animation position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have player and his climb animation, so i want climb_end animation position save to game object player. I don't want return back to player position after last animation frame. Thanks

Comment: Rather unclear what you're talking about. Maybe check off Apply Root Motion?

Comment: Sorry for my english, yes, I have uncheck apply root motion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the animation is not set to loop (uncheck looping in the animation file).

Also, make sure "Has Exit Time" in the animation controller's climb_end animation state is unchecked. This might be causing the animation state to move onto another animation after it's finished running.